# Word Wrap in CSS3

Tags: javascript, css, word-wrap

Is there any other way to word-wrap a text inside a div?
I can't use word-wrap in CSS since I can only use CSS1 and some CSS2.

*Use javascript or CSS

Thank you!

```
.test_wordWrap {
  position: absolute;
  top: 45px;
  left: 20px;
  width: 250px;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

Comment: Why you're limited by CSS1/2? word-wrap is widely supported by browsers.

Comment: Environment issues :D

Comment: can you update your question with html code and css you have written ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help:

```
.myClass {
     white-space: normal;
     overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: thank you for you answer! but it hides the rest of the text, hence the hidden.

"WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW" should be displayed to 

"WWWWWWWWWWWW
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWW"

Comment: try: overflow: visible instead.

Comment: maybe problem is with div size? Can I see Your div declaration an class please?

Comment: position: absolute;
  top: 45px;
  left: 20px;
  width: 250px;
  white-space: normal;
  overflow: visible;

it doesn't seem to work

Comment: add this: word-break: break-all, as mentioned in one of answers

Answer (score 1):

Following css attributes will do the job

```
word-break: break-all;
```

Comment: this is a css3 method

Answer (score 0):

Try it is...

html

```
   <div class="wraptext">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</div>
```

css

```
.wraptext{
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:50px;
 }
```

Comment: this answer is the same as above. :(

Comment: not the same beacuse the  Css (white-space:nowrap) && (white-space:normal) are different..

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one baby :)

`p.wrap {
    width: 11em; 
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}`

`<p class="wrap"> This paragraph is very long long long long but not long enough to say how much you love a person lol</p>`

Comment: "I can't use word-wrap"

Comment: why you can't use it baby?

Comment: Can only use CSS1 and CSS2. (environment issues)

Comment: Ok got it baby you can use `white-space: nowrap`

Comment: this is fine when it's in a sentence. like 

<p class="test_wordWrap">this is my paragraph. blah blah blah blah blah</p>

but since i'm gonna word-wrap a single word, it doesn't work. :(

Comment: I made a jsfiddle just for you baby https://jsfiddle.net/an1d1na9/1/ Hope it's solve your problem.

Comment: word-break is a css3 function. :O

Comment: word-wrap is still a css3 function

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
<div class="wordwrap">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>

.wordwrap
{
 width : 50px;
/* wrap long text and urls */
white-space: pre; /* CSS 2.0 */
white-space: -pre-wrap; /* Opera 4-6 */
white-space: -o-pre-wrap; /* Opera 7 */
white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Mozilla */
word-wrap: break-word; /* IE 5+ */
}
```